# Deleting Lines, which match a particular Identifier from another file

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, perl, bioinformatics

I have 2 files. File 1, has an identifier (eg. `D7MHBF:11:1449:1988`) and every new entry starts with `@`. It has few more fields, which are not important in our analysis.

File 2 consists of a column of Identifiers. If the Identifier of File 2 is exactly matching with the Identifier of File 1 then, delete the whole three-line entry in File 1.(P.S. Every entry starts with @). 
**File 1**:

```
@D7MHBF:11:1449:1988  1:N
NGCCCATTCTATGCAACAAATTCAACAAAGTCTCCCA
+
#1=DDFFDFHHDHIGGFIIIIIIIHHIHIGDGIGGEH
@D7MHBF:11:1681:1959  1:N
NGGTTTAGAGCCTGTATTTTGAACGTAATAGCAGGGT
+
#1=ADDFFHHDDHEHIHJJJICCFHGEIGJGGGIJJF
@D7MHBF:11:1778:1946  1:N
NTGTGGGTTCAACAATGGGCTCATTGCCATCAGCGAG
+
#1=ADDFDHHGHFHGGIIJJJGIIJIFIIJJJIJIIJ
@D7MHBF:11:1854:1955  1:N
NTTGATTGTGCTTCTTATGAGCAAAAATGTTGATGAC
+
#1=DFFFFHHHGHHIJEHIIGGGGIJJJJIHIIHIII
@D7MHBF:11:1903:1972  1:N
NACTACTATACTATGAAGTGGCTATGACAATTGTCTT
+
#1=DFFFFHHHGHHIJEHIIIGGGGIJJJJIHIIHII
```

**File 2:**

```
D7MHBF:11:1449:1988
D7MHBF:11:13844:51576
D7MHBF:11:13838:51641
D7MHBF:11:1778:1946
D7MHBF:11:1903:1972
```

Expected Output:

```
@D7MHBF:11:1681:1959  1:N
NGGTTTAGAGCCTGTATTTTGAACGTAATAGCAGGGT
+
#1=ADDFFHHDDHEHIHJJJICCFHGEIGJGGGIJJF
@D7MHBF:11:1854:1955  1:N
NTTGATTGTGCTTCTTATGAGCAAAAATGTTGATGAC
+
#1=DFFFFHHHGHHIJEHIIGGGGIJJJJIHIIHIII
```

Comment: In your example not every line starts with an @, this does not confirm with your description, please correct one or the other.

Comment: Hi Anthon, Every line starts with @. This is the format of the Fastq File. One complete line consists of 4 lines.

Comment: @Anthon by _line_, the OP means _entry_.

Comment: @terdon Yes that is now clear, thanks. (I had not seen the OP comment while not having been addressed with `@`). We are fortunate the OP doesn't use line for what I would call a file as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution (copy/paste into your terminal):

```
perl -pe 's/\n/xxx/g' file1 | sed 's/xxx@/\n@/g; s/xxx$/\n/' |
 grep -vFf file2 | sed 's/xxx/\n/g'
```

#### Explanation

There are three separate commands there, each of which [pipes](http://www.linfo.org/pipe.html) (`|`) its output to the next. The first two just get each record on a separate line by replacing `\n` with `xxx` (the `xxx` is just so we can know where the line breaks are). If you run them alone they do:

```
$ perl -pe 's/\n/xxx/g' file1 | sed 's/xxx@/\n@/g; s/xxx$/\n/'
@D7MHBF:11:1449:1988  1:NxxxNGCCCATTCTATGCAACAAATTCAACAAAGTCTCCCAxxx+xxx#1=DDFFDFHHDHIGGFIIIIIIIHHIHIGDGIGGEH
@D7MHBF:11:1681:1959  1:NxxxNGGTTTAGAGCCTGTATTTTGAACGTAATAGCAGGGTxxx+xxx#1=ADDFFHHDDHEHIHJJJICCFHGEIGJGGGIJJF
@D7MHBF:11:1778:1946  1:NxxxNTGTGGGTTCAACAATGGGCTCATTGCCATCAGCGAGxxx+xxx#1=ADDFDHHGHFHGGIIJJJGIIJIFIIJJJIJIIJ
@D7MHBF:11:1854:1955  1:NxxxNTTGATTGTGCTTCTTATGAGCAAAAATGTTGATGACxxx+xxx#1=DFFFFHHHGHHIJEHIIGGGGIJJJJIHIIHIII
@D7MHBF:11:1903:1972  1:NxxxNACTACTATACTATGAAGTGGCTATGACAATTGTCTTxxx+xxx#1=DFFFFHHHGHHIJEHIIIGGGGIJJJJIHIIHII
```

As you can see, now each entry is on its own line. So, you can now pass this to `grep` and tell it to print all lines that **do not** (`-v`) match any of the patterns found in file2 (`-f file2`). This prints:

```
$ perl -pe 's/\n/xxx/g' file1 | sed 's/xxx@/\n@/g; s/xxx$/\n/' | grep -vFf file2  
@D7MHBF:11:1681:1959  1:NxxxNGGTTTAGAGCCTGTATTTTGAACGTAATAGCAGGGTxxx+xxx#1=ADDFFHHDDHEHIHJJJICCFHGEIGJGGGIJJF
@D7MHBF:11:1854:1955  1:NxxxNTTGATTGTGCTTCTTATGAGCAAAAATGTTGATGACxxx+xxx#1=DFFFFHHHGHHIJEHIIGGGGIJJJJIHIIHIII
```

Finally, we run it through `sed` again, to replace `xxx` with newlines and get the desired output:

```
$ perl -pe 's/\n/xxx/g' file1 | sed 's/xxx@/\n@/g; s/xxx$/\n/' | 
    grep -vFf file2  | sed 's/xxx/\n/g' 
@D7MHBF:11:1681:1959  1:N
NGGTTTAGAGCCTGTATTTTGAACGTAATAGCAGGGT
+
#1=ADDFFHHDDHEHIHJJJICCFHGEIGJGGGIJJF
@D7MHBF:11:1854:1955  1:N
NTTGATTGTGCTTCTTATGAGCAAAAATGTTGATGAC
+
#1=DFFFFHHHGHHIJEHIIGGGGIJJJJIHIIHIII
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved with the pattern matching and text processing features of the language TXR.

Note that `@@` encodes a literal `@` character to be matched.

```
@(next "file2.txt")
@(bind idhash @(hash :equal-based))
@(repeat)
@id
@(do (set [idhash id] t))
@(end)
@(next "file1.txt")
@(bind outstream @(open-file "file3.txt" "w"))
@(repeat)
@@@ident@\ @rest
@  (collect)
@line
@  (until)
@@@(skip)
@  (end)
@  (require (not (gethash idhash ident)))
@  (output :continue outstream)
@@@ident @rest
@    (repeat)
@line
@    (end)
@  (end)
@(end)
```

Run:

```
$ txr del.txr 
$ cat file3.txt 
@D7MHBF:11:1681:1959  1:N
NGGTTTAGAGCCTGTATTTTGAACGTAATAGCAGGGT
+
#1=ADDFFHHDDHEHIHJJJICCFHGEIGJGGGIJJF
@D7MHBF:11:1854:1955  1:N
NTTGATTGTGCTTCTTATGAGCAAAAATGTTGATGAC
+
#1=DFFFFHHHGHHIJEHIIGGGGIJJJJIHIIHIII
```

Comment: Hi.. It says txr: command not found

Comment: Executables of txr here. OSX 10.7.3 included: http://www.nongnu.org/txr/#downloads

Answer (score 0):

Awk solution:

```
BEGIN {
  while (getline < "file2.txt") {
    idhash[$0]
  }
  RS="@"
  FS=" "
}

{ if ($1 in idhash) printf("%s%s", NR == 1 ? "" : "@", $0); }
```

Run:

```
$ awk -f del.awk file1.txt
@D7MHBF:11:1681:1959  1:N
NGGTTTAGAGCCTGTATTTTGAACGTAATAGCAGGGT
+
#1=ADDFFHHDDHEHIHJJJICCFHGEIGJGGGIJJF
@D7MHBF:11:1854:1955  1:N
NTTGATTGTGCTTCTTATGAGCAAAAATGTTGATGAC
+
#1=DFFFFHHHGHHIJEHIIGGGGIJJJJIHIIHIII
```

Comment: Hi Kaz, It is not giving me the right output. I am getting  Output:               D7MHBF:11:1449:1988  1:N
    NGCCCATTCTATGCAACAAATTCAACAAAGTCTCCCA
    +
    #1=DDFFDFHHDHIGGFIIIIIIIHHIHIGDGIGGEH
    D7MHBF:11:1778:1946  1:N
    NTGTGGGTTCAACAATGGGCTCATTGCCATCAGCGAG
    +
    #1=ADDFDHHGHFHGGIIJJJGIIJIFIIJJJIJIIJ

Comment: It is giving wrong ouput.

Comment: Worsk for me with `mawk` on an Ubuntu system.

Comment: I am using a Mac Terminal. I do not know if that is the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Srilakshmi I have OSX in a VirtualBox image; I will try it later.